# Check the validity of an Object each time this one is modified

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, design-patterns

I have this business logic in a library in Typescript, where I can create an Event and manage his state. Like `DRAFT`, `PUBLISHED`, `IN_VALIDATION`...

Here is the `EventModel.ts`

```
import {EventStateEnum} from "..";

export class EventModel {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public state: string,
        public isFree: boolean,
        public prices: EventPricesInterface[],
    ) {
        this.state = state || EventStateEnum.DRAFT;
    }
}
```

By default when a user is using the library to create an event, this one is in `DRAFT`. 
But after you can change this `state` to `PUBLISHED`.

I would like to add a control (listener) at the object level, which check that if the event is in `PUBLISHED` and this one is not free `isFree: false` and this one do not have prices `prices: null`.

Because we can not create a paid event which does not contain any prices.

How can I achieve to add a listener who always check the validity of my object with my business logic?

The idea is to be sure to always check the integrity of an object when this one is instantiate and updated.

Is there a design pattern to do that?

Comment: [This](https://www.monterail.com/blog/2016/how-to-build-a-reactive-engine-in-javascript-part-1-observable-objects) might help.

Comment: you might have a look on `get`ters and `set`ters as they come with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Examples) ... make the integrity check part of any setter's implementation.